# Colored text to the console

Tags: nushell

How can I echo colored text to the console?

In Powershell I can do this:

> write-host _info_ -fore Yellow   -Back Blue
>
> write-host _error_ -fore Yellow  -Back Red
>
> write-host _warning_ -fore White   -Back DarkYellow
>
> write-host _succes_ -fore Yellow  -Back Green
>
> write-host verde -fore Yellow  -Back Green -nonewline ; write-host blanco -fore black -back white -nonewline ; write-host rojo -fore yellow -back red

How can I do the same with nushell?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

I have not found this information in your documentation.

Comment: Color formatting is a matter of the terminal that a shell is outputting to. You may find your answer at: https://github.com/nushell/nu-ansi-term (the nushell ANSI terminal)

Comment: Now I found the answer:
$'(ansi { fg: y bg: g attr: b }) verde (ansi { fg: b bg: w attr: b }) blanco (ansi { fg: y bg: r attr: b }) rojo' 

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this. You've already discovered the `ansi` command but you can also just do it with escapes and interpolated strings.

Here's an example using the `ansi` command with interpolation using `$""`

```
echo $"(ansi red)Nushell(ansi reset)"
```

Now to see what's going on "under the hood" you can run this command.

```
echo $"(ansi red)Nushell(ansi reset)" | debug -r
```

Which results in something like this.

```
String {
    val: "\u{1b}[31mNushell\u{1b}[0m",
    span: Span {
        start: 277827,
        end: 277859,
    },
}
```

Now it's a little easier to see that there are ansi escapes making all this happen. So, that means we can do something like this with the same result.

```
echo "\e[31mNushell\e[0m"
```

The key here is that, in nushell, double quotes mean to translate escapes. If you were to use single quotes or backtick quotes, you'd just get a string instead of a red string.